# Differentiating _delete_by_query tasks in a multi-tenant index

Tags: elasticsearch

Scenario:
I have an index with a bunch of multi-tenant data in Elasticsearch 6.x.  This data is frequently deleted (via `_delete_by_query`) and populated by the tenants.

When issuing a `_delete_by_query` request with `wait_for_completion=false`, supplying a query JSON to delete a tenants' data, I am able to see generic task information via the `_tasks` API.  Problem is, with a large number of tenants, it is not actively clear who is deleting data at any given time.

My question is this:
Is there a way I can view the query for which the `_delete_by_query` task is operating on?  Or can I attach an additional param to the URL that is cached in the task to differentiate them?

Side note: looking at the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/tasks.html I see there is a `description` field in the `_tasks` API response that has the query as a String, however, I do not see that level of detail in my `description` field:
`"description" : "delete-by-query [myindex]"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont believe elastic stores `what fired the query`. However, when you use `wait_for_completion=false`, you get a taskId - you could create a lookup on your application end so each corresponding query that fires `_delete_by_query` will have its own taskId for you to lookup

Comment: @PolynomialProton - I actually use that functionality for another part of my application, but the core problem is that either I, or another process/thread running separate, cannot view who/what kicked off the deletion request, unless it knows the taskID.  For instance, if I want to view who is currently deleting data, I cannot pair task IDs to particular tenants via the `_tasks` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to identify queries is to add the [`X-Opaque-Id` HTTP header](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#_identifying_running_tasks) to your queries:

For instance, when deleting all tenant data for (e.g.) User 3, you can issue the following command:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'X-Opaque-Id: 3' -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://localhost:9200/my-index/_delete_by_query?wait_for_completion=false -d '{"query":{"term":{"user": 3}}}'
```

You then get a task ID, and when checking the related task document, you'll be able to identify which task is/was deleting which tenant data thanks to the `headers` section which contains your HTTP header:

```
  "_source" : {
    "completed" : true,
    "task" : {
      "node" : "DB0GKYZrTt6wuo7d8B8p_w",
      "id" : 20314843,
      "type" : "transport",
      "action" : "indices:data/write/delete/byquery",
      "status" : {
        "total" : 3,
        "updated" : 0,
        "created" : 0,
        "deleted" : 3,
        "batches" : 1,
        "version_conflicts" : 0,
        "noops" : 0,
        "retries" : {
          "bulk" : 0,
          "search" : 0
        },
        "throttled_millis" : 0,
        "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
        "throttled_until_millis" : 0
      },
      "description" : "delete-by-query [deletes]",
      "start_time_in_millis" : 1570075424296,
      "running_time_in_nanos" : 4020566,
      "cancellable" : true,
      "headers" : {
        "X-Opaque-Id" : "3"                             <--- user 3
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks!  Through using this, I also found that if I issue the following request: `GET _tasks?actions=*/delete/byquery&group_by=none&detailed=true` supplying the same header for this request, I can get in flight tasks that were queued with that header